# How to get a value outside its brackets in java

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Which horse do you want to win, enter in 1-5");

String horsechoice = Input.next();

int randomhorse = (int)(Math.random()*5+1);

int horsechoice1 = Integer.parseInt(horsechoice);

System.out.println(randomhorse);

if (horsechoice1 == randomhorse){
    System.out.println("You win");
    int money = x + i;
    System.out.println("You have $"+money+ " remaining.");
}else if(horsechoice1 != randomhorse){
    System.out.println("You Loose");
    int money = x - i;
    System.out.println("You have $"+money+ " remaining.");
}
```

My goal is to get the int money outside of its brackets and to another part of my code further on. I feel like it should be a lot easier then I am making it.

Comment: If you declare `money` before the braces, you can use it _after_ the braces.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the variable before the braces , then set the value inside the braces. You can give it an initial value of 0 if you like (sometimes the compiler will force you to give an initial value .)  This is the only way.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be something simple!

Answer (score 1):

The brackets define the outer limits of a scope block. When the program moves past the end of the scope block then all the variables declared within go 'out-of-scope' and are destroyed. So that's what's happening with your `money` variable. So if you declare it outside of your brackets it won't go out of scope when you leave the scope block. You can then give it a value inside the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I would change it like this (after `String horsechoice = Input.next();`)

```
int money = 0; // The money
int randomhorse = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);
int bet = 50; // A bet
int horsechoice1 = Integer.parseInt(horsechoice);
System.out.println(randomhorse);

if (horsechoice1 == randomhorse) {
  System.out.println("You win");
  money += bet; // Add the bet to money
} else { // if (horsechoice1 != randomhorse) { // <-- why retest?
  System.out.println("You Lose"); // Not Loose
  money -= bet; // Subtract the bet from money
}
System.out.println("You have $" + money
    + " remaining."); // <-- Print once.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare the variable outside of "its brackets", but set the value inside of them.

Like so:

```
int money = 0; // declare here

if (horsechoice1 == randomhorse){
    System.out.println("You win");
    money = x + i; // set here
    System.out.println("You have $"+money+ " remaining.");
}else if(horsechoice1 != randomhorse){
    System.out.println("You Loose");
    money = x - i; // set here
    System.out.println("You have $"+money+ " remaining.");
}
```